# Android random generate chars

Tags: java, android

How to generate random chars ?

Random numbers like this: :

```
public static int random() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int x = generator.nextInt(10000);
    return x;
}
```

I need to draw something like: zCs3v3b1b6 just random chars

Answer (score 2):

```
public static char random() {
     Random generator = new Random();
     char x = (char)(generator.nextInt(96) + 32);
     return x;
}
```

This would generate a random char.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
           builder.append(random());
     System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```

This would generate a string with 8 random characters

Comment: First example: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char

Answer (score 0):

See below link : http://www.asciitable.com/

```
public static char randomSeriesForThreeCharacter() {
Random r = new Random();
char random_3_Char = (char) (48 + r.nextInt(47));
return random_3_Char;
}
```